# How to show $\frac 1 e \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n^x}{n!}$ is always an integer for $x \in \mathbb N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-sum

The series $$\frac 1 e \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n^x}{n!}$$ converges to an integer by some of my computations using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Fe)%5Csum(+n%5E20%2Fn!),+n%3D0+to+infty) with $x \in \mathbb{N}$. I don't succed to show that this series is always integer by evaluating using the partial sum of it because the partial sum is complicated for every integer $x \geq 0$ .Then I have this question:

What is the partial sum of :$$\frac 1 e \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n^x}{n!}$$
for fixed integer $x$ such that $0\leq x < n$ and how I can prove it always integer ?

Comment: $n$ is a dummy summation variable.  What does it mean to say $x<n$?

Comment: I meant the sum can't up to n^n/n!

Comment: You wrote an infinite sum.  If you meant something else, you should edit.

Comment: @lulu:  zeraoulia asks about the partial sums of the series.  That said, I agree that $x< n$ is meaningless.

Comment: @ for every fixed integer x we have  an integer sum

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  You've written an infinite sum.  Maybe you have something else in mind, who knows?  Perhaps it would help if you wrote out an explicit example.  What happens if $x=2$, say?

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik:  I am confused.  If $x$ is an integer, then any finite sum of the form $\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{n^x}{n!}$ is a positive rational.  In particular $\frac{1}{e}$ times this sum is irrational, so not an integer.  What am I missing?

Comment: @JasonDeVito, Try to fix x

Comment: $x$ is fixed in my comment (although my comment still applies if $x$ is allowed to vary, so long as it stays in integer). Could you do as @lulu asks and write out an explicit example?

Comment: @JasonDeVito see this : for x=2 ,https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Fe)sum(+n%5E2%2Fn!)),+n%3D0+to+infty

Comment: I think you are confused.  The $x<n$ bit doesn't mean anything and you should remove it.  As to your sum, these are the [Bell Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellNumber.html) and the formula you want can be found on the page I linked to.

Comment: Maybe OP means: find a formula for the partial sums so that he/she can prove the infinite series converges to an integer, or maybe not, since $x<n$ thing still doesn't make sense.

Comment: [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C15%2C52%2C203&language=english&go=Search) is the OEIS reference for the values.

Comment: @lulu, Thanks , and they are the same values i have got for every integer x

Comment: From you link, you don't mean partial sums at all - you mean the full infinite series.  I still don't understand what $x<n$ means in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with [Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials). We have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{e^{nz}}{n!} = \exp\left(e^z\right)$$
and by applying $\frac{d^m}{dz^m}$ to both sides we get
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n^m e^{nz}}{n!} = Q_m(e^z)\cdot\exp\left(e^z\right),\qquad Q_m(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x] $$
so the evaluation at $z=0$ leads to
$$ \frac{1}{e}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n^m}{n!} = Q_m(1)\in\mathbb{Z} $$
as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}$Denote$$
S_m = \frac{1}{\e} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{j = 0}^{m - 1} (k - j),
$$
then$$
S_m = \frac{1}{\e} \sum_{k = m}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{j = 0}^{m - 1} (k - j) = \frac{1}{\e} \sum_{k = m}^\infty \frac{1}{(k - m)!} = \frac{1}{\e} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = 1 \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Now denote$$
T_m = \frac{1}{\e} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{k^m}{k!}.
$$
Note that for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $T_m$ is a linear combination of $T_0, \cdots, T_{m - 1}, S_m$ with combination coefficients being integers, by induction on $m$, $T_m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $x \ge 0$, let:
$$T(x) = \sum_{ n \ge 0 } \frac{n^x}{n!}$$
Then you have $T(0) = \sum_\limits{ n \ge 0 } \frac{1}{n!} = e $, and for any integer $x\ge0$,

$$
T(x+1) = \sum_\limits{ n \ge 0 } \frac{n^{x+1}}{n!} = \sum_\limits{ n \ge 0 } \frac{ n \cdot n^x}{n!} = \sum_\limits{ n \ge 1 } \frac{n^x}{(n-1)!} = \sum_\limits{ n \ge 0 } \frac{(n+1)^x}{n!}    
$$

Now you can expand the inner term using the binomial theorem to get a recurrence formula:
$$
T(x+1) =
\sum_\limits{ n \ge 0  }\sum_\limits{ 0 \le k \le x } \frac{C_k^x \cdot n^k}{n!} =\sum_\limits{ 0 \le k \le x }  C_k^x \sum_\limits{ n \ge 0  } \frac{ n^k}{n!}
= \sum_\limits{ 0 \le k \le x }  C_k^x \cdot  T(k)
$$

Therefore, you can easily show that $T(x)$ is an integer multiple of $T(0) = e$ for any $x \in \mathbb{N} $.